# Proof by example?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was doing some linear algebra exercies. One I did is this: Prove that the union of two subspaces $U,W$ of $V$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if one contains the other.

My proof is this: If one is a subset of the other $U \subset W$ then the union is $W$ which by assumption is a subspace. If neither is contained in the other there exists an example where the union is not a subspace: let $V$ be the xy-plane, $U$ the x-axis and $W$ the y-axis. Then the union is not closed with respect to addition.

My question is whether it is valid to prove something by example? How would you prove this in another way?

Comment: No, in this case, an example is not enough, since you need to prove that the union is never a subspace if one of them is not contained in the other, rather than "the union might not be a subspace".

Comment: You can't prove a statement like "for all U,V,W..." by verifying a single case by example. The only time an example is going to prove something is if the statement you are proving is like this "there exists an example such that..." . Then it makes sense that you only need to exhibit one case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Suppose that $U\cup W$ is a subspace of $V$.

Since $U$ isn't contained in $W$ and $W$ isn't contained in $U$ then there's $u\in U$ and $u\not \in W$ and $w\in W$ and $w\not \in U$ and let $t=u+w$. Prove that $t\not \in U\cup W$. Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

The "$\Rightarrow$" is trivial, so we shall concentrate on the "$\Leftarrow$".
If $U\not\subset W$, that means $\exists u \in U:\ u \notin U\cap W \not\ni w \ni W$.
Now all we need is for a Subspace $A\subset V$ and vectors $a\in A, v\in V \setminus A$ we have
$$a+v \notin A$$
If we can prove that, we are done.

**Hint**
Consider a basis of $A$ (which must exist for $A$ is a subspace) and it's properties; conclude that $a+v$ cannot be written as a linear combination of any such basis vectors.